# BeautifulSoup parsing and organizing data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html structured like the exemple below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="otherattr">
                <div id="listalbum">
                    <div id="9067" class="album">album: <b>"Name of the album"</b> (2001)</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div id=91453, class="album">album: <b>"other Name of album"</b> (2007) </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div id=56739, class="album">album: <b>"another album"</b> (2012) </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item"> </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my goal would be to extract tags with id = *somenumber* (that number btw is always different for every tag), and extract also the other tags with *listalbum_item* -for the sake of simplicity we suppose that into those tags there is some text or some link, doesn't matter-

As you see this html is organized to show the title of an album, and all the songs in that album. 
I want to create some structure (we say a dictionary) like:

```
dix = {'album_1' : ['song1','song2','song3','song4'] , 'album_3' : ['song1','song2','song3','song4']}
```

how can you do it? the problem for me is that 'id' has a number that changes everytime ( and this is just an exemple but I need to parse a very big site with lots of artist (and consequently with lots of albums and songs) and I have problems organizing the data in and ordinate way. I was only able to create a list with all song tag, but I need to separate the song for the album they belong to

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far .

Comment: You can try to use [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) with regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to First identify the album and then search for `find_next_siblings()` and then verify that `find_previous_sibling()` match with album attribute `ID`

**Code**:

```
data='''<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="otherattr">
                <div id="listalbum">
                    <div id="9067" class="album">album: <b>"Name of the album"</b> (2001)</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song1</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song2</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song3</div>
                    <div id="91453" class="album">album: <b>"other Name of album"</b> (2007) </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song1</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song4</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song2</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song3</div>
                    <div id="56739" class="album">album: <b>"another album"</b> (2012) </div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song5</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song1</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song3</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song2</div>
                    <div class="listalbum_item">song4</div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

album={}

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("#listalbum > .album"):
    name=item.find_next('b').text
    songs = []
    for song in item.find_next_siblings('div',class_="listalbum_item"):

        if song.find_previous_sibling('div',class_='album')['id'] == item['id']:
            songs.append(song.text)

    album[name]=songs

print(album)
```

**Output**:

```
{'"Name of the album"': ['song1', 'song2', 'song3'], '"another album"': ['song5', 'song1', 'song3', 'song2', 'song4'], '"other Name of album"': ['song1', 'song4', 'song2', 'song3']}
```

Comment: thanks man! btw what is the function of the hashtag and the point in the soup.select() row?

Comment: that is the syntax of the `id` in css selector check the official doc: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/